# Can't add index to an object into loop writen in a VueJS method

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a loop that works fine in a pure javascript file but it returns the following error in console trying it into a VueJS method:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

The script:

```
  let matches = []
  for (let firstTeam = 0; firstTeam < teams.length; firstTeam++) {
    for (let secondTeam = firstTeam + 1; secondTeam < teams.length; secondTeam++) {

      matches[date].push({
        teamA: teams[firstTeam],
        teamB: teams[secondTeam]
      })
      date++
      if (date > c) {
        date = 1
      }
    }
  }
```

What's wrong with that?
Why the push method doesn't work into the loop instance?

Answer (score 0):

matches[date] needs to be init as an array

```
matches[date]=[]
matches[date].push({
    teamA: teams[firstTeam],
    teamB: teams[secondTeam]
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @FanCheung but what I need is that date could be dynamic. If you take a look at the code you can see that it increments in each iteration